# How to create unique drop down lists on top of each column in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a data like the following:

```
a1    a2    a3   a4   a5   

aa    bb    cc   dd   ee
ff    gg    rr   ff   rr
ff    ff    rr   dd   jj
cc    cc    cc   cc   cc
aa    ee    ee   tt   tt
```

This data is in Excel.

I want to create a drop down list on top of each column which should show only unique entries of each column.

Drop down list of first column should show only

```
aa ff cc
```

and same for each column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the space between the headers and data, Select all of the headers and add a filter the filter will show a drop down like you describe

screenshots

[image]

[image: http://www.accountingweb-cgi.com/editorial/excel_102808/Excel-Filtering-101---Figure-1.jpg]

Comment: Can you be more elaborate please. May be a screenshot would be great. I added the filter on selecting the headers but not getting the list.

Comment: have you removed the space between the headers and the data (the space being the entire row)

Comment: +1 .. for nice image .. =)

Answer (score 0):

The autofilter utility on Data menu when invoked always lists unique items in the list.There is no need to use any formula or formatting.